# Extreme Programming : is the life cycle used?

Tags: extreme-programming

I am researching about Extreme Programming, and saw in Scott Ambler book 'Agile Modelling : effective practices for extreme programming'  that XP has an lifecycle.(exploration phase, planning phase, iterative development,maintenance   So whenever  someone wants to use XP process  to develop, can we  follow this lifecycle for developing a software?

Comment: Of course.  You *can* do whatever you want to.  Whether it actually produces the desired result or not is a different matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey for what I have read, the lifecycle can guide us in applying the values, rules and principles that XP has. II want to  use it as a lone developer,  so following this lifecycle,  and not having all the constraints of heavyweight processes

Comment: What would be the purpose of following a formal software development lifecycle if you're the sole developer?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'd like to see something more formal for loan developers. Too many have reinvented the wheel, but it turns out to be rough on the edges at best.

Comment: @JeffO Does any development method prevent the re-invention of the wheel?

Comment: @RobertHarvey not really a formal approach, its like a guidance, because  one needs to know when to use the right rules, principles and values

Comment: There's no such thing as "the right rules, principles and values," other than "always get better."  There are several software development methodologies; they all have differences.

Comment: @FrankHileman - No, but that doesn't mean every lone developer has to be the one to do it just like I don't need to write yet another javascript framework.